# .click() button doing nothing in Selenium python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to build a bot for Nike.com.
I'm rotating user agent, automation blink is hidden and have done everything needed (Even using VPN).

URL : https://www.nike.com/ca/t/air-force-1-pixel-shoe-txmVNP/CK6649-100
Size:2

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import requests
import sys
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from fake_useragent import UserAgent
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait


options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
ua=UserAgent()
userAgent=ua.random
options.add_argument("--log-level=3")
options.add_argument("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled")
options.add_argument(f'user-agent={userAgent}')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.minimize_window()
driver.execute_script("Object.defineProperty(navigator, 'webdriver', {get: () => undefined})")
driver.execute_cdp_cmd('Network.setUserAgentOverride', {"userAgent": 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.53 Safari/537.36'})
URL=input("Enter URL : ")
SIZE=input("ENter Size : ")
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get(URL)
time.sleep(5)


print("Starting again")

while(True):
    
##        try:
    s_size=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="buyTools"]/div[1]/fieldset/div/div['+SIZE+']/label')
    s_size.click()
    time.sleep(1)
##    try:
    print('here')
    time.sleep(5)
##    WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//*[@id="floating-atc-wrapper"]/div/button[1]'))).click()
    add_to_bag=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="floating-atc-wrapper"]/div/button[1]')
    time.sleep(3)
    add_to_bag.click()
    print('1')

    break

time.sleep(1)
while(True):
    try:
        move_to_cart=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="nav-cart"]/a/div/span')
        move_to_cart.click()
        break
    except:
        time.sleep(1)
```

This code is selecting the required size, and **also Clicks on Add to Bag button** with clicking animation on website but after that also nothing happens even when I manually click on Add To Bag button or reload website nothing happen.

The only way out is open link in new tab and do all things manually
Can anyone give me a workaround for this.

I think selenium is doing its work its getting blocked by website